# Link css file to ejs file

Tags: css, ejs

How can i link a CSS file to ejs file,I tried the below solution but not sure what i did wrong

**.css code:**

```
    body {
      background:url('img.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
    }
```

**.ejs code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Feddback Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <form action="" method="POST" class="form">
      <h1>Store Ownership Feedback</h1>
      <div>
        <label" for="name">Problem</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="box"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="request">Feedback</label>
        <textarea name="request" id="request" cols="30" rows="10" class="box"></textarea>
      </div>
      
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
      </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

**.js code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/views'));
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});
```

**Files director:**
.js:/public
.ejs:/public/views
.css:/publice/views/CSS

Answer (score -1):

The generally recommended structure is that the main .js file should be in the root section and the css files should be in the public section. Below, I am sharing an example structure with the aim that it may help.

Directory Structure:
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhUIz.png)

Forwarding Static:
[public static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Bzx.png)

Importing css on header.ejs:
[Import css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rywFr.png)